# Blazor making a field read only

Tags: c#, html, blazor, readonly

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <span>County Code</span>
    <InputText class="@("cursor-disabled "+ input100)" readonly="true"  disabled="true" name="addressLine1" placeholder="County Code..." @bind-Value="_model.CountyCode" />
    <ValidationMessage For="@(() => _model.CountyCode)" />
</div>
```

I have the HTML attribute **readonly** and **disabled**
But when the page is rendered, it does not respect this.

Comment: Both `readonly` and `disabled` are "Boolean attributes", which confusingly mean they only take their names as values, or nothing at all. At least, in HTML. I don't know about Blazor-flavored Razor. So you can try using `readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled"` and see if that works. Then try `readonly disabled` if it doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

you can do it in this way, you can set the `IsDisabled` as per your requirement.

```
@code{
    protected bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
}

<InputText class="@("cursor-disabled "+ input100)" disabled="@IsDisabled" name="addressLine1" placeholder="County Code..." @bind-Value="_model.CountyCode" />
```

Comment: Was going to asnwer.. BlazorFiddle demo'ing this: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/icwdmx6j